# Windows phone 7 - control camera zoom in via application

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am creating one application where I required to control the camera controls via my app such as camera capture, camera zoom in, zoom out, flash on/ off and so on.

Normally, in iPhone, API are available which can control the execution of hardware. I have tried to achieve same in windows phone 7 using silverlight. I have found the code to control the camera on event via code but not able to find any thing so that via button or slider, I can zoom in, zoom out.

I tried the reference video http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Inside+Windows+Phone/Inside-Windows-Phone-16-Mango-Camera-APIs and downloaded the code but still not found anything specific.

My question is that is it possible in windows phone 7 to have this feature and if so can anyone please guide me for this?

I also found one thing where when the camera is open, the images are coming in reverse direction :)

Please help me out of this.

Thanks,

David.

Answer (score 0):

To zoom, you have to manually process the image.
You will need to add your own + and - zoom buttons and keep track of the zoom level.
Then, to show a zoomed viewfinder, you need to get the previewbuffer in a loop and zoom the image yourself to the current zoom level and then display it.
When the user takes a picture, you will apply the same zoom processing to the image in the CaptureImageAvailable event handler before saving.